# Query to get items not in a list of IDs but which are related to items in the list

Tags: mysql

I've been looking at this for too long and I've have lost all capacity for logic. Pointers/help much appreciated.

I have three tables as below, with the columns that matter.

Table: Categories

```
+-------+--------------+
| catID | catName      |
+-------+--------------+
|     1 | somename     |
|     2 | stringname   |
|     3 | thirdcat     |
|     4 | stringcat    |
|     5 | stringother  |
|     6 | sixthcat     |
+-------+--------------+
```

Table: Products

```
+-----+------+
| pID | pCat |
+-----+------+
|  22 |    1 |
|  33 |    1 |
|  44 |    7 |
|  55 |    9 |
+-----+------+
```

Table: Prodcats

```
+-----+-------+
| pID | catID |
+-----+-------+
|  22 |     2 |
|  22 |     6 |
|  33 |     3 |
|  33 |     5 |
|  44 |     3 |
|  44 |     6 |
|  55 |     5 |
|  55 |     6 |
+-----+-------+
```

I have a list of category IDs. I need to use this list to return categories with a particular string in catName.

I want categories added to this list if (from categories):

```
catName LIKE %string% AND catID IN ($mycats)
```

Obviously no problem there.

However I also need to return categories 2 and 5 (containing 'string') but ONLY if they are related (in prodcats) 2to a product that is in catID 1.

That's where my head broke.

It may be useful to know the following:

- The IDs in $mycats may or may not occur as pCat in the products table.
- There will only ever be either one or two items in $mycats - if there are two, one will always be a cat whose name contains the string I am looking for, the second one will never be.

**EDITED: - added sample table data above and an example below to make this clearer.**

An example would be: 
$mycats=1,4

I would need to get catID 4 - whose names both contains  'string'. That's the easy bit.

BUT I also want to get catID 2 and 5, because they too contains string and although are not in $mycats are attached to a pID in the table prodcats which is in catID 1 in products.

I hope that makes it a bit clearer. It's like mud to me at this point.

Comment: two questions; is pCat (in the products table) an ID? and can i assume that that pCat is not in the prodcats table for that pID?

Comment: I've updated the question with better table outlines and an example which will hopefully be clearer. You are correct though, pCat from the products table will never occur in prodcats related to the the pId.

Comment: It would be easier to implement this kind of logic in a programming language from which you submit the SQL queries. 
Otherwise you could try to set up a separate query for your catIDs 2 and 5 and then join the results using `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secondary category ids that are also to be included from your requirement may be expressed as:

```
select c.*
from Product p
join Prodcats pc on pc.pID = p.pID
join Categories c on c.catID = pc.catId and c.catName like '%string%'
where pCat in (1,4)
```

Now you just `union` that with your original query:

```
select *
from Categories = pc.catId 
where catID in (1,4)
and c.catName like '%string%'
union
select c.*
from Product p
join Prodcats pc on pc.pID = p.pID
join Categories c on c.catID = pc.catId and c.catName like '%string%'
where pCat in (1,4)
```

Notes:

- `union` removes duplicates automatically, so no need for `distinct`. (`union all` preserves duplicates)
- this query should perform quite well - the two paths to categories are in a separate queries, so optimization will be good
- the condition for category name is in the join's `on` clause, because such clauses execute *as the join is made*, whereas putting the condition in the `where` cluase would be executed *after all possible joins are made*, which means a lot more joins are made. Bottom line: It's much faster this way

Answer (score 0):

ok, I *think* I've figured out what you're after.

The trick is to work backwards. First get the categories that are linked via the product (selected using the `associatedCategories` derived table below). Then join back against those categories that match the string.

```
select * from
categories
inner join (
    select catID from
    products
    inner join prodcats on products.pID = prodcats.pID
    where
    pCat in (1,4)
) associatedCategories on categories.catID = associatedCategories.catID
where catName LIKE '%string%';
```